# raycast interaction system

Tags: c#, unity3d

I've written a solution to make creating new interactions easier but wanted feedback to see if there is a more effective way of going about this.

I've written a script called interactable which is what the raycast on the player looks for. The interactable than says that the player has interacted with it. Then, another script that does the action can take that information to play the event. I did it this way to prevent having to add multiple checks in the raycast function for every different interaction.

here is the raycast function

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class player_abilities : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSensitivity;
    public float movementSpeed;

    public GameObject notebook;
    public Text notebookText;
    
    public GameObject note;
    public Text noteText;
    
    public Transform playerBody;
    private float xRotation = 0f;
    public Transform camera;
    CharacterController _controller;
    public Vector3 velocity;
    public float timeMoving;

    public Item selectedItem;
    public Item[] Inventory;
    public int currentItemIndex = 0;
    public Text selectedItemName;
    public Image selectedItemImage;
    
    //Audio
    private AudioSource _audio;
    public AudioClip soundWritingNote;

    public void Interact()
    {
        timeMoving = 0;
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(camera.position, camera.forward, out hit, 8))
        {
            Interactable _interactable = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();
            if (_interactable != null)
            {
                _interactable.Interact();
            }
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }
    public void InteractItem()
    {
        timeMoving = 0;
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(camera.position, camera.forward, out hit, 8))
        {
            Interactable _interactable = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();
            if (_interactable != null && _interactable.requiredItemName != "")
            {
                if (_interactable.requiredItemName == selectedItem.name)
                {
                    _interactable.InteractItem(true);
                    selectedItem = null;
                    RemoveAt(ref Inventory,currentItemIndex);
                    currentItemIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    _interactable.InteractItem(false);
                }
            }
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }

    public Item[] AddItemToArray(Item[] original, Item itemToAdd) {
        Item[] finalArray = new Item[ original.Length + 1 ];
        for(int i = 0; i < original.Length; i ++ ) {
            finalArray[i] = original[i];
        }
        finalArray[finalArray.Length - 1] = itemToAdd;
        return finalArray;
    }
    
    public void RemoveAt<Item>(ref Item[] arr, int index)
    {
        for (int a = index; a < arr.Length - 1; a++)
        {
            // moving elements downwards, to fill the gap at [index]
            arr[a] = arr[a + 1];
        }
        // finally, let's decrement Array's size by one
        Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length - 1);
        Debug.Log("ItemRemoved");
    }
}
```

here is the interactable

```
public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool hasBeenInteractedWith;
    
    public bool itemDoesMatch;
    public bool failedItemMatch;
    public string requiredItemName;
    

    
    public void Interact()
    {
        hasBeenInteractedWith = true;
    }
    public void InteractItem(bool match)
    {
        if (match)
        {
            itemDoesMatch = true;
        }
        else
        {
            failedItemMatch = true;
        }
       
    }
}
```

and lastly, here is an example of an event script that uses the interactable

```
public class OpenChickenGate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Interactable _interactable;
    void Start()
    {
        _interactable = gameObject.AddComponent<Interactable>();
        if (SceneStateController.chickenGateOpen)
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().Play("open_chicken_gate 0");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(_interactable != null && _interactable.hasBeenInteractedWith)
        {
            // interaction complete, open gate
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("gate_unlocked", true);
            SceneStateController.chickenGateOpen = true;
            DeleteGateCollider();
            _interactable.hasBeenInteractedWith = false;
        }
    }

    public void DeleteGateCollider()
    {
        Destroy(GetComponent<BoxCollider>());
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be great. Thank you and have an awesome day